# Why doesn't Xcode allow me to use presentViewController?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, sprite-kit

I want to implement a share function in my SpriteKit game. I have a button for that and I'm trying to do this in a `Gamescene`. That's the code I've found for that:

```
func handleTwitter(sender: AnyObject) {
// Check if Twitter is available
if(SLComposeViewController.isAvailableForServiceType(SLServiceTypeTwitter)) {
// Create the tweet
let tweet = SLComposeViewController(forServiceType: SLServiceTypeTwitter)
tweet.setInitialText("I want to share this App: ")
tweet.addImage(UIImage(named: "shareImage"))
self.presentViewController(tweet, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

It looks very logical but I have a problem in

```
self.presentViewController(tweet, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Xcode tells me that `GameScene doesn't have a member called "presentViewController"`. Do I need to implement this code only in `GameViewController.swift`? If so, how would I use it in a game scene and others? I have two scenes with share buttons in it. Or the issue is in `SLComposeViewController`? I don't understand what is the problem, do I need to declare some kind of delegate in a `GameScene` to make it work?

Comment: Thats right, you can not present viewController for a scene, you can presentViewController from viewController. if you want to present it uou should delegate feom your scene to your viewacontroller and present it.

Comment: Could you explain how to do it? What delegate should I declare and where?

Comment: What should I do with it? I don't understand!

Comment: could you solve the problem?

Comment: @gbesler yes! You need to use this code in your GameViewController. Then use NSNotification to invoke this function in the gamescene. I will post example here in a few hours:)

Comment: @gbesler see my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So for those who suffer from that problem. The answer is:

`func handleTwitter()` should be in `GameViewController`. Then in `viewDidLoad` you'll need to post an NSNotification:

```
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "handleTwitter", name: "tweet", object: nil)
//You can use any name in the name field
//selector should be the name of a function without braces
//that you want to pass to other scenes
```

Then you should go to your GameScene or GameOverScene or whatever and make a global function, that responds to that NSNotification:

```
func gameOvetTweet() {
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName("tweet", object: nil)
}
//make sure that name in 'postNotificationName("THIS NAME"...' 
//is matching name that you've passed in GameViewController.
//In this example it is "tweet"
```

And then, the only thing that is left to do is to post your function wherever you want. For example:

```
if self.nodeAtPoint(location) == self.twitterButton {
          gameOverTweet()
        }
```

That's all. I also use it for ads.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code that works for me.

```
UIViewController *vc = self.view.window.rootViewController;
[vc presentViewController:tweet animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Hope this helps

Comment: I mean can You show more info how to use where and full code ?

Comment: this isn't swift is it?

Answer (score 0):

Anyone using swift:
`self.view?.window?.rootViewController!.presentViewController(viewController!, animated: true, completion: nil)`